# how to implement pull to refresh in Xamarin using c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am still new to Xamarin and C# and I need your help on how to implement the Pull to refresh in a programmatic fashion.

I searched the whole internet for some tutorial on this but I didn't find anything because everyone is using XAML instead of c#. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See if the IsPullToRefreshEnabled property exists in your listViewJson

if it exists, implement this way, passing what has from xaml to c #.
[link](https://xamarinhelp.com/pull-to-refresh-listview/)

Comment: but XAML is used in the first part

Comment: listViewJson.IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true;

Answer (score 1):

Use this way: `listViewJson.IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true;`

similarly add a command to update the list you want, for example: `listViewJson.RefreshCommand` relating some binding to the command.

Also add in the IsRefreshing method a binding for the list you want, for example: `listViewJson.IsRefreshing`

In sequence in your viewmodel add:

```
private bool _isRefreshing = false;
public bool IsRefreshing { 
get { return _isRefreshing; }
set {
    _isRefreshing = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
    }
}
```

And for the update command add:

```
public ICommand RefreshCommand
{
    get {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;

            await RefreshData();

            IsRefreshing = false;
        });
    }
}
```

to you bind the properties RefreshCommand and IsRefresinhg you need to do this for example:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = ViewModel;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeString");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtText, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: do I have to assign something to listViewJson.RefreshCommand and listViewJson.IsRefreshing